# How to plot ylabel in panda MultiIndex Dataframe

Tags: pandas, plot, dataframe, multi-index

I need to plot a MultiIndex Dataframe with ylabels from level 0 of the columns. The Dataframe is as follows:

```
PCs                                pc1           pc2           pc3  \
explained_variance_ratio  9.977643e-01  2.196399e-03  3.275875e-05   
wavelength                                                           
540.00                        0.015110     -0.004772     -0.018467   
540.05                        0.015110     -0.004772     -0.018467   
540.10                        0.015110     -0.004772     -0.018467   
540.15                        0.015110     -0.004772     -0.018467   
540.20                        0.015110     -0.004772     -0.018467   
540.25                        0.015110     -0.004772     -0.018467   
540.30                        0.015110     -0.004772     -0.018467   
540.35                        0.015110     -0.004772     -0.018467   
540.40                        0.015081     -0.004226     -0.017577   
540.45                        0.015081     -0.004226     -0.017577  
.......
```

The ylabel should be pc1, pc2, pc3.... with wavelength the xlabel.

I have tried the following it doesn't work:

```
pca_df.plot(subplots=True, sharex=True, title='Principle Components', \
    legend=False, y=list(pca_df.columns.levels[0]))
```

error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 1716, in plot_frame
    ser = frame[y]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1652, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1697, in _getitem_array
    return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1166, in take
    indices, len(self._get_axis(axis)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1438, in _maybe_convert_indices
    if mask.any():
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'
```

Also tried:

```
pca_df.plot(subplots=True, sharex=True, title='Principle Components', \
    legend=False)
plt.ylabel(pca_df.columns.levels[0])
```

Although it plots the ylabel that covers all plots is simply:

```
Index([u'pc1', u'pc10', u'pc2', u'pc3', u'pc4', u'pc5', u'pc6', u'pc7', u'pc8', u'pc9'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do most of the formatting on the ax or axes itself after calling `plot`. 
Try this:

```
axes = pca_df.plot(subplots=True, sharex=True, title='Principle Components', legend=False)
for ax, label in zip(axes.ravel(), pca_df.columns.levels[0]):
     ax.set_ylabel(label)
```

I find it much easier to use the axes API rather than trying to fit it all into the plot method call. Note that when subplots is True, the plot method returns an array of axes, which you have to access by indexing or iteration as I've done here. The `.ravel` is a nice way of dealing with two dimensional arrays which you get when your figure has multiple rows and columns, but it still works if the array is only one dimensional.